# pass argument into sort function

Tags: php, sorting

I am using a uasort function like this:

```
uasort($entity_list, 'sortArray');

function sortArray($a, $b) {
  if($a['fixed_column_name'] == $b['fixed_column_name']) {
      return 0;
  }

  return ($a['fixed_column_name'] < $b['fixed_column_name']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

I would like to pass a parameter to the sortArray function, like this:

```
uasort($entity_list, 'sortArray($arg)');

function sortArray($a, $b, $arg) {

  $larg = $arg;

  if($a[$larg] == $b[$larg]) {
      return 0;
  }

  return ($a[$larg] < $b[$larg]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.3+ (and you really should at this point in time), you can use closures:

```
uasort($entity_list, function ($a, $b) use ($arg) {
    if ($a[$arg] == $b[$arg]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[$arg] < $b[$arg]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Otherwise, you'll have to work around doing the same thing using `global` variables (oh noes!) or a class.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a class:

```
$sorter = new Sorter($arg);
usort($entity_list, array($sorter, "sort")); //will use $sorter->sort as callback

class Sorter {
    function __construct($arg) {
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }
    function sort($a, $b) {
        // sort using $a, $b and $this->arg
    }
}
```

Closures are nicer though ^^

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Example #4 using a closure on the [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) page of the PHP manual. The same technique can be used with all the basic sorts, including uasort()